# Java square brackets behind parameter name "int g[]"?

Tags: java, arrays, parameter-passing

I have to translate code from Java to OpenCL

I have this function given in Java:

```
float dot(int g[], double x, double y, double z) {
    return g[0]*x + g[1]*y + g[2]*z;
}
```

This is a possible call:

```
dot(g[i], x, y, z);
```

Where: `i = int` and `g = usual array of int`.

What is this weird `int g[]` parameter thing? I've never seen this before and didn't find anything about "square brackets after parameter name".

The only thing I can imagine, that this is some sort of offset thing, like its translates `g[0]*x` to `g[i+0]*x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is this weird int g[] parameter thing?

It's just another way of writing `int[] g` and means exactly the same thing: The argument is typed `int[]`, so needs to be a reference to an array of `int`. From [JLS §10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2):

> The `[]` may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both.

Regarding your call:

> This is a possible call:
>
> ```
> dot(g[i], x, y, z);
> ```
>
> Where: `i` = `int`, and `g` = usual array of `int`.

No, that isn't a possible call, as you discovered. :-) You need to pass in an array reference, not an `int`, so perhaps:

```
dot(g, x, y, z);
```

Comment: Okay... after looking it up is see that g is a 2D jagged array: [][]. Together with your explanation it makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

In Java, writing this...

```
int[] a;
```

...is the same as...

```
int a[];
```

It is a hangover from the early days of Java to help C/C++ programmers adopt the language more easily (and port code).

Java allows declarations such as...

```
int a, b, c[];
```

...but this is discouraged (because it is a C/C++ hangover).

In Java, the convention is to move away from this and have one declaration per line, i.e....

```
int a;
int b;
int[] c;
```

Answer (score 1):

`int g[]` in the parameter means passing an integer type array as a parameter. So you cant do `dot(g[i], x, y, z);` here, because it will pass only a single index.

Suppose If you have an array `arr[10]`, you can write `dot(arr, x, y, z);`